# How can I change the name attribute value for an annotation in java selenium

Tags: java, selenium, annotations

I have an annotation in java selenium as
**Annotation**

```
    @FindBy(name= "passFirst0" )
    public WebElement txtPassengerFirstName;
```

I want to change the attribute 'name' s value to "passFirst1" for another textbox present on my testing app's page during run time and assigned that a data value.
I have written two codes for the same but both are not working.

**First One:**

```
    String strModifiedNameAttribute = txtPassengerFirstName.getAttribute("name");
    strModifiedNameAttribute = strModifiedNameAttribute.replace("0", "");
    strModifiedNameAttribute = strModifiedNameAttribute + i;
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('name', '" + strModifiedNameAttribute + "' )", txtPassengerFirstName);
    txtPassengerFirstName.sendKeys("Amit");
```

**Second One**

```
  String strModifiedNameAttribute = txtPassengerFirstName.getAttribute("name");
    strModifiedNameAttribute = strModifiedNameAttribute.replace("0", "");
    strModifiedNameAttribute = strModifiedNameAttribute + i;
    exampleUsage(rmtDriver, txtPassengerFirstName, "name", strModifiedNameAttribute);
    txtPassengerFirstName.sendKeys("Amit");
```

**Method to call setAttribute**

```
   public static void exampleUsage(RemoteWebDriver rmtDriver, WebElement element,
        String strAttributeName, String strAttributeValue) {
    setAttribute(rmtDriver, element, strAttributeName, strAttributeValue);
}
```

**SetAttribute methods**

```
 public static void setAttribute(RemoteWebDriver rmtDriver, WebElement element,
        String attName, String attValue) {
    try {
        rmtDriver.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute(arguments[1], arguments[2]);", element, attName, attValue);
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Please assist me to change the name attribute value at run time so that I can assigned it a data value.

Comment: So what you are trying to do is modify the HTML on the page using Selenium? Or are you trying to interact with two objects on the screen (firstPass0, and firstPass1), and update both of them.